# How update records from a collection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update all the reports of a user that are already created and now that I update their information I need to update the reports and change their status. This is my code

```
public function updateReportsUsers(Request $request)
    {
        $reports = Report::where('user','like','%'.$request->user.'%')->where('status ','=','DIGITATED')->get();
        return $reports->update($request->all());

}
```

But when I run the function I get this error.

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->get()` returns a `Collection` of `Report` model instances, and you can't updated a Collection like that. Either replace the `->get()` with `->update()`, or loop over your results and update one-by-one:

```php
return Report::where('user', 'like', '%' . $request->user . '%')
->where('status', '=', 'DIGITATED')
->update($request->all());

// OR

$reports = Report::where('user', 'like', '%' . $request->user . '%')
->where('status', '=', 'DIGITATED')
->get();

foreach ($reports as $report) {
  $report->update($request->all());
}

return true;
```